# Shell script to pipe first 3 words from a file into a new file, remove them and loop

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file with hundreds of 'FirstName LastName Email' in a single string.  I need to separate the string into 1 set per line

```
FirstName LastName Email
FirstName LastName Email
FirstName LastName Email
```

etc

I am struggling to remove the first 3 words from the file after I pipe them into a new file, this way when the script loops, it will read the next 3, pipe, remove, etc.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' asd >> asd2 | cut -d' ' -f1-3 asd
```

I know cut is not right but I honestly cannot find a way of removing the first 3 words, I am only finding 'sed' to remove a whole line.

Comment: removing three columns in the output of `awk '{print $1, $2, $3}'` would return nothing.

Comment: I've removed cat, not sure why I did that.  Basically, the first part works, it pipes the first 3 words into asd2 then those same 3 words need to be removed from asd, this way when I rerun the command, it will pipe the next 3 words

Comment: This would be a really simple question to answer if it were more specific than "in a single string" ... what if someone's first name is "Billy Bob", are they 1st,last,email separated by tabs, spaces, \r, \n, \r\n ???

Comment: @NeronLeVelu You made a wrong edit..

Comment: @Avinash Raj sorry if it is the case.

Comment: @JCats, could you confirm/infirm this so we can adapt the request if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `|` symbol here.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' asd >> asd2; sed -i 's/^ *[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+//' asd
```

You could add `[^[:blank:]]` instead of `[^ ]` in the above command. Change the regex to `'s/^ *[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ *//'` to remove also the spaces which exists after the third word.

Comment: OMG, why a downvote. His question is different at very first. See the revisions.

Comment: Maybe you want to write this in your answer with a link to the revisions, or write a comment to OP that he should mark it as an edit or make a rollback.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`xargs`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=xargs)...

```
$  cat asd
FirstName1 LastName1 Email1 FirstName2 LastName2 Email2 FirstName3 LastName3 Email3 ...

$ xargs -n3 < asd
FirstName1 LastName1 Email1
FirstName2 LastName2 Email2
FirstName3 LastName3 Email3
...
```

xargs syntax:

```
xargs -nN [command=echo [args]]
```

1. `-n3` means run command with 3 arguments each time.
2. If command is not specified, default command being executed is `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` should do it all in one go:

```
awk -vRS=" "  '{ORS=NR%3?RS:"\n"}1' asd 
FirstName LastName Email
FirstName LastName Email
FirstName LastName Email
```

By setting `RS` to one blank, one record is one word.
Then sett `ORS` to one space or new line after three word.

It can be shorten some to:

```
awk -vRS=" " 'ORS=NR%3?RS:"\n"' asd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for WORD in $(cat asd)
do
    if [[ $i == 3 ]]
    then
        i=0
        printf '\n' >> asd2
    fi
    printf "%s" "$WORD " >> asd2
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Edit: Wow, I'm rusty, it took me some time to write this crappy script.

Edit: This puts every three words on a new line, but names and such must not have spaces.

Edit: If your names have spaces in them, then you'd need a script to search for the "@" character (for emails) and add a new line character after that word.

Answer (score 0):

If you're conceding awk, you might as well use ruby and get an answer in one step:

```
ruby -e '$stdin.read.split.each_slice(3) {|x| puts x.join " "}'
```

Answer (score 0):

generate the final file at once

```
sed 's/\(\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{2\}[^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1\
/g' Org.txt > NewFormated.txt
```

removing the 3 first word only (the request)

```
sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{2\}[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}//' Org.txt > New.txt
```

in both case take the 3 group of non space separate by space (in fact 2 + 1) and use or remove it